# "In your time" or "at your time"?

Tags: differences

I have a partner who lives sumptuously in a different time zone.

I've been wondering which is the correct way of putting it:

> 11 p.m. in your time

or

> 11 p.m. at your time

Thank you!

Comment: The expression I frequently hear and read is simply "11 p.m. your time."

Comment: *sumptuously*??

Comment: @Jim The living always look more sumptuous in a different time zone.

Comment: You might as well also consider: "11 p.m. *on* your time" and "11 p.m. *by* your time"

Comment: In my time "in my time" meant "back in the good old days", and "in your timezone" meant, uh, in your timezone. (Though sometimes "your time" would be used instead.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither works well. *In your time* suggests that you are referring to your partner's past.

> E.g. We sleep earlier these days. 11pm in your time (30 years ago) would have been like 7pm today.

The second doesn't sound idiomatic to my ears.

Try

> at 11pm, your time.

Comment: thank you @Lawrence, will use "at 11pm, your time." instead